# Accessing array within an array in multiple database rows

Tags: php, arrays

I have a database structure that looks like the following:

[image]

I am trying to store the prices as a variables so that if I reference cage_linear_feet it will display 225.

I have tried the following code:

```
   $sql  = "SELECT * from pricing WHERE region = '$region' ";

   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

   while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

   $test[] = array($rows['field']=>$rows['price']);

   }

   print_r ($test);
```

This displays the following:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [cage_linear_feet] => 225 ) [1] => Array ( [cage_doors] => 1800 ) )
```

How do I access the "225" and "1800" values ensuring that if more records are added to the db it will still pick up the correct records. E.g as the $test[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNpMc.png) which is cage_doors may change if records are added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is that there is no point in wrapping the key-value pairs in their own separate arrays. I would change this line:

```
$test[] = array($rows['field']=>$rows['price']);
```

to this:

```
$test[$rows['field']] = $rows['price'];
```

The data association will be maintained in the key=>value pairs of one associative array ($test). So echo $test['cage_linear_feet'] ---> 225

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks

Comment: Sure, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set `field` as the array-key

```
$sql  = "SELECT * from pricing WHERE region = '$region' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 $test[$rows['field']] = $rows['price']);
}
print_r ($test);
```

No  you should be able to reference by `field` like so:

```
echo $test['cage_doors'];
// returns 1800
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the column 'field' unique? If so, do this:

```
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $test[$rows['field']] = $rows['price'];
}
```

This will set the key in the array to the field, i.e.

`Array('cage_doors' => 1800)`

If its not unique, I recommend doing something like:

```
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $test[$rows['field'] . '_' . $rows['pricing_id']] = $rows['price'];
}
```

This will set the key in the array to the field and the pricing id, which makes it unique, i.e.

`Array('cage_doors_2' => 1800)`